# Online check in problems for Air Japan NH805 / Air Canada AC6230 from BKK to NRT

Tags: japan, check-in, ana

Online check in problems for Air Japan NH805 / Air Canada AC6230 from BKK to NRT. 
Why, when booking with Air Canada and Star Alliance partner Air Japan, can one seemingly NOT check-in online in Bangkok for the leg back from BKK to NRT (Tokyo?)

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Have you asked Air Japan?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not the Air Japan help desk.

Comment: Are you sure you're on the right website?  The "NH" flight number is for All Nippon Airways (ANA) http://www.ana.co.jp, not Japan Airlines (JAL).

Comment: @jpatokal you are onto something because ANA and Air Canada are both Star Alliance while Japan Airlines is not. Want to elevate this to an answer?

Comment: It's probably because your flight is flight 806, not 805. 805 is the reverse direction.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is one or both of these two:

1. **Are you sure you've got the right website?** [Flight NH805](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/ANA806) is on [All Nippon Airways](http://www.ana.co.jp/) (NH/ANA), not Japan Airlines (JL/JAL).  There is also an ANA subsidiary called [Air Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Japan), but AFAIK they don't fly to Bangkok and their flights are effectively indistinguishable from mainline ANA anyway.
2. **Are you sure you've got the right flight number?** Flight NH805 is *from* Tokyo/NRT *to* Bangkok, not the other way around.  The flight *from* Bangkok to Tokyo is [NH806](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/ANA806).

Comment: When I put in NH805 (or NH806) into Flight Aware it helpfully says that this All Nippon flight is operating as Air Japan 805 (or 806).